# ffmpeg fix audio of MP4 files

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have a few MP4 files that when I play on my computer it plays fine. However, if I put it on a usb and try to play on TV the audio is muted. I've tried a few different TVs and same problem. If I play it on my fire TV with vlc player then it works. So it makes me think the audio codec isn't supported. Is there a way using ffmpeg to quickly re-encode just the audio so it works with the TV? I used the vlc convert tool and selected the YouTube HD profile and that works but it takes forever to encode as it's a 2hr long video

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mp4`. It's just to get file info so no converting is happening.

Comment: @llogan here is the output screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/7cIOLj3.png

Comment: Audio is already AAC so there goes my initial guess. Lazy suggestion is to try re-muxing: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: Let me try that and report back.

Comment: @llogan so I tried that, the output file of re-muxing only came to 448MB whereas the original file is 2.17GB. I tested the 448MB file and it plays and also plays audio this time on the TV but seems to be messed up as it seems to skip lots of scenes hence how it's become very small. But strange thing is total duration is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried re-muxing the mp4 file as @llogan suggested with ffmpeg but it was messing the file up even though it was fixing the audio issue. I then tried a tool called My MP4Box GUI which is very old but that tool re-muxed the video very well and file size remains same and the audio now works on the TV